# НЕ с краткими прилагательными (2)

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему *Все мы не идеальны* ("не" с краткими прилагательными отдельно), но *Все мы несовершенны* ("не" приставка)?

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае *отрицается идеальность,* во втором *утверждается несовершенство.* Слово *"неидеальный"* тоже есть, и можно употребить и краткое прилагательное слитно. Во втором случае также естественнее утверждать несовершенство, чем отрицать совершенство, но и раздельное написание не будет грубой ошибкой.